# CloudFront Issue loading text, instead showing html

Tags: caching, amazon-cloudfront, request-headers, response-headers

I am using CloudFront with the following policies.

**Cache Policy**: Disable

**Origin Request Policy**:

```
cookies_config {
    cookie_behavior = "all"
  }
  headers_config {
    header_behavior = "whitelist"
    headers {
      items = ["Host", "Accept-language]
    }
  }
  query_strings_config {
    query_string_behavior = "all"
  }
```

But the problem is that in one of the section of website showing HTML instead of text/design.

**Expected Result**

[image]

**Actual Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the origin request policy of CloudFront, missing some header which I wasn't able to find specific, so putting header as AllViwers, it is showing the expected result.

***Origin Request Policy***

```
cookies_config {
    cookie_behavior = "all"
}
headers_config {
    header_behavior = "allViewer"
}
query_strings_config {
    query_string_behavior = "all"
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).